# Flash as3 3d Engine or which language

Tags: flash, 3d, away3d

I develop a project like http://www.homestyler.com/floorplan/

I know flash AS3 with away3d or alternativa3d engine but yesterday i see the link above. In this Autodesk Floorplanner project, which language used for develop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The homestyler floorplan project isn't built with AS3, rather it's a Javascript based app.

I believe it's based on the WebGLRenderer ThreeJS library... either way it's very nicely done!